# How do I resize a Silverlight 3 application and all child controls and keep aspect ratio

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, resize, aspect-ratio

I'm building a Silverlight 3 application and I would like it to resize depending on the size of the web browser.

I have found   http://community.irritatedvowel.com/blogs/pete_browns_blog/archive/2008/07/04/How-to-Resize-a-Silverlight-2-App-and-Keep-the-Same-Aspect-Ratio.aspx

But the solution suggested doesn't seem to work on silverlight 3 (one of my child controls disappears off the screen when I resize).

Any suggestions?

/Jimmy

Comment: Which control is it that is disappearing?  The ScaleTransform should affect all controls in the viewable area.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is something else.
I have a UserControl (the one I want to resize) and the root element is a Gridinside that grid I have another usercontrol containing a couple of paths (lets call it: PathControl) at the top left corner.
When I resize my app (accordning to the sample above) my "PathControl" gets enlarged but also moves outside of the visible area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the SL toolkit ViewBox is what you need?

- http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%201&referringTitle=Home&ANCHOR#Viewbox
- http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/11/06/silverlight-toolkit-viewbox.aspx
- [http://www.liquidjelly.co.uk/supersearch/?q=silverlight%20viewbox&lang=en-GB](http://www.liquidjelly.co.uk/supersearch/?q=silverlight%20viewbox&lang=en-GB#)